# Torrent lens in 13.10

Tags: lenses, bittorrent, 13.10

I recently updated to 13.10, and installed the torrents lens. The torrent lens won't show up even after restarting. Is there a way to make it work with smart scopes?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build for saucy 13.10 in launchpad. [unity-lens-torrents](https://launchpad.net/~scopes-packagers/+archive/ppa)